# Is there a function to get N nearest numbers of the specific number?

Tags: php, numbers

Is there a built-in function to get nearest N numbers of the specific number using PHP, please? I mean, we have for example number `5`. Now, I need to get an array like this `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`.

So, I'm looking for some function `nearestNumbers(5, 2)`, where `5` - specific number, and `2` - amount of numbers up/down  to specific number, which does `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. Thanks!

---

In reality, when using Laravel pagination with custom `$elements`.. this looks really strange:

```
[
$paginator->currentPage()-2,
$paginator->currentPage()-1,
$paginator->currentPage(),
$paginator->currentPage()+1,
$paginator->currentPage()+2
]
```

Comment: the [range function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php]) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Probably not the best solution as far as I only know the middle number, and not starting / ending numbers.. but @phparkle finished your idea. Great, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do with a built-in function is probably `range`:

```
range( $paginator->currentPage()-2, $paginator->currentPage()+2 )
```

You could write a helper function like this:

```php
function nearestNumbers( $x, $d ) {
    return range( $x - $d, $x + $d );
}
```

You could use `min` and `max` to limit the range:

```php
function nearestNumbers( $x, $d, $lim ) {
    return range( max( $x - $d, 1 ), min( $x + $d, $lim ) );
}
```

Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Comment: There are no boundary checks for pages <= 0 or >= max.

Comment: Yes, this is enough for now. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I will check boundaries later in code, so this isn't problem for me right now.. but I agree there should be a better solution including negative numbers or etc. Thanks!